# Interpret terrain type from height data and/or geolocation

Tags: geolocation, terrain

I have downloaded a large subset of the STRMGL1 Dataset, and have further split each entry down into 5km by 5km tiles. I now need to start classifying each tile by terrain types. Are there any automated methods for doing so from the height data and/or the Geolocation of each tile? For example, is there a database of terrain types at different locations?

Any terrain types will work, but I would prefer to have at least some of the following:
OPEN - TUNDRA - OASIS - STEPPE - HILL - DESERT - MOUNTAIN - FOREST - MARSH - BOG - SWAMP

Multiple tags per tile are allowed.

Comment: There isn't much correlation between elevation and terrain (except for the dearth of swamps above 8000 meters). You need to do the same thing you did with elevation -- find a data source and prepare it for use. It's unlikely you'll find 3m resolution on terrain.